# Gap between navigation bar and first UITableViewCell

Tags: swift, uitableview, uisearchcontroller

I have a UITableViewController with a search controller embedded in the navigation bar.

When the view shows in a modal, there is a gap between the first row and the navigation bar.

[image]

here is my implementation. Some code has been redacted for confidentiality. But anything regarding view controller setup should still be there:

```
import Foundation

class SearchViewController: UITableViewController {

    fileprivate lazy var searchController: UISearchController = {
        let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.searchBar.showsCancelButton = true
        searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
        return searchController
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupTableView()

        navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = BrandColor.appleDarkGray
    }

}

extension ExploreSearchViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {

    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        if let searchText = searchBar.text {
            tableView.refreshControl?.beginRefreshing()
            searchedText = searchText
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - UITableView Methods
extension ExploreSearchViewController {
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return searchResultsProvider.searchResults.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        guard searchResultsProvider.canLoadNextPage else { return }

        // handle paging here...
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard searchResultsProvider.searchResults.count > indexPath.row else { return UITableViewCell() }

        // Setup search result cell here...
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        // Handle cell did tap here...
    }

    @objc private func refresh() {
        searchResultsProvider.refreshResults()
    }

    // MARK - Table View Helpers

    private func setupTableView() {
        registerCells()
        self.tableView.backgroundColor = .white
        self.tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .always
        self.tableView.refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
        self.tableView.refreshControl?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refresh), for: .valueChanged)
        self.tableView.useDefaultPageLoadingIndicator()
        self.tableView.setBackgroundViewIfEmpty(message: Self.searchInitialMessage, remedyButton: nil)
    }

    private func registerCells() {
        //Register Table View Cells here...
    }
}
```

Has anyone seen this kind of issue before? I can't move the top edge insets up because then the refresh control will be hidden behind the navigation bar.

Anyone seen this behaviour before? If so, how did you solve it?

Comment: Could you please show some code on how you implement your tableview? Can't really reproduce the issue for the limited information provided...

Comment: Have you tried ```tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
```? Does it help?

Comment: @paky sorry. Edited the post with my code. Some code has been redacted. But everything in regard to the table view, search controller and view setup is there.

Comment: Still cannot reproduce the gap from the provided code, and I've tried to add the navigationController/tableView/searchBar using storyboard and programmatically but still got no luck. Let me make a guess,  are you adding a tableHeaderView or some Insect in your useDefaultPageLoadingIndicator() or setBackgounrdViewIfEmpty()?

Comment: useDefaultPageLoadingIndicator() adds a UIActivityIndicator into the table's footerView.

setBackgroundViewIfEmpty() checks if the table view is empty. If it is, it adds a UILabel and an optional UIButton. The button is generally used to take the user somewhere that will add content to the table view.

Comment: @paky I seemed to have solved it. The problem was actually on the view controller that presented the TableView.

we were instantiating the table view like this: UITableView(style: .grouped)

by switching it to .plain it works.

I think the original writer of that table view wanted the search results to have categories but they never got around to implementing the sections.

Comment: Ahhhh silly me, didn't think of the tableView style when going through your code. Good to hear that you fixed it. Have a nice day ;)

Answer (score 0):

The issue was caused by the table view style was set to `.grouped` on the previous view controller.

Setting the style to `.plain` solved this issue.

I believe the reason grouped style causes the blank space is because its adding an empty section header above the cells.